# how to compile kernel 3.14 (downloaded from kernel.org) on ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

I have ubuntu 14.04 and I have a project where ill be modifying the kernel (something to do with its scheduler).

Our project supervisor told us to use kernel 3.14 specifically from kernel.org .
I couldn't find any tutorial on how to compile and boot kernel downloaded from kernel.org .

I have found this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide?action=show&redirect=KernelTeam%2FKernelGitGuide and it seems you have to use only kernels from **Ubuntu kernel repositories** - is that right?

thanks for the help

Comment: use troval's link. you will get updated source of kernel. https://github.com/torvalds/linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compile my kernels on my Ubuntu machine like this:

1)

```
mkdir kernel-build
```

2)

```
cd kernel-build/
```

3)

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

4)

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.14.tar.xz
```

5)

```
tar -xJvf linux-3.14.tar.xz
```

6)

```
cd linux-3.14
```

7)

```
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
```

8)

```
yes "" | make oldconfig
```

**8.1) is optional:**

```
make menuconfig
```

9)

```
make -j`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` bzImage modules
```

10)

```
sudo make modules_install install
```

11)

```
sudo reboot
```

This should be enough.

EDIT: step 3 is if you need to disable some modules, which means that you can skip **step 8.1**, if you do not know what are you doing.

Comment: If my Answer helped please Accept it.

Comment: make -jgetconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` bzImage modules` - on which step are we talking about?

Comment: @user5411628 on the **step 9**

Comment: oki great . and Now when loading ubuntu and getting to Grub window ill see an option to load it with kernel 3.14?

Comment: at stage 8 I get the following error :  yes "" | make oldconfig
Makefile:332: /home/snadav54/kernel-build/linux-3.14/scripts/Kbuild.include: No such file or directory
make: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
I geuss I dont have the file oldconfig . what to do?

Comment: @user5411628 Sorry about that, it should work now. Please start over. do a **rm -rf kernel-build** first to avoid any problems.

Comment: **ill see an option to load it with kernel 3.14?** Yes it will be there.

Comment: i got to step 9 and it stopped with this lines :  LD      security/integrity/integrity.o
  CC      security/integrity/integrity_audit.o
^Cmake[2]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [security/integrity] Error 2
make: *** [security] Interrupt
 no idea :/

Comment: Hm, strange because I just finished and the Kernel compiled and works fine for me.

Comment: does it metter where is kernel_build folder located?

Comment: Now its Working. After I did all above steps , I couldnt see the new kernel in grub menu . I consulted with a friend and he told me that maybe it happens because Im running ubuntu through vmware . He told me to enter the following command : " sudo grub-install /dev/sda " . Then It worked ..  :)

Comment: I added simple hello world system call and it took me like 2 hours to recompile . should it be like that?